# Kubelet Master stays in KubeletNotReady because of cni missing

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet, calico, cni

Kubelet has been initialized with pod network for Calico :

```
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16 --image-repository=someserver
```

Then i get calico.yaml v3.11 and applied it :

```
sudo kubectl --kubeconfig="/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf" apply -f calico.yaml
```

Right after i check on the pod status :

```
sudo kubectl --kubeconfig="/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf" get nodes
NAME              STATUS     ROLES    AGE     VERSION
master-1   NotReady   master   7m21s   v1.17.2
```

on describe i've got cni config unitialized, but i thought that calico should have done that ?

```
MemoryPressure   False   Fri, 21 Feb 2020 10:14:24 +0100   Fri, 21 Feb 2020 10:09:00 +0100   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Fri, 21 Feb 2020 10:14:24 +0100   Fri, 21 Feb 2020 10:09:00 +0100   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Fri, 21 Feb 2020 10:14:24 +0100   Fri, 21 Feb 2020 10:09:00 +0100   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            False   Fri, 21 Feb 2020 10:14:24 +0100   Fri, 21 Feb 2020 10:09:00 +0100   KubeletNotReady              runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
```

In fact i have nothing under /etc/cni/net.d/ so it seems it forgot something ?

```
ll /etc/cni/net.d/
total 0
```

```
sudo kubectl --kubeconfig="/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf" -n kube-system get pods
    NAME                                       READY   STATUS                  RESTARTS   AGE
calico-kube-controllers-5644fb7cf6-f7lqq   0/1     Pending                 0          3h
calico-node-f4xzh                          0/1     Init:ImagePullBackOff   0          3h
coredns-7fb8cdf968-bbqbz                   0/1     Pending                 0          3h24m
coredns-7fb8cdf968-vdnzx                   0/1     Pending                 0          3h24m
etcd-master-1                       1/1     Running                 0          3h24m
kube-apiserver-master-1            1/1     Running                 0          3h24m
kube-controller-manager-master-1    1/1     Running                 0          3h24m
kube-proxy-9m879                           1/1     Running                 0          3h24m
kube-scheduler-master-1             1/1     Running                 0          3h24m
```

As explained i'm running through a local repo and journalctl says :

```
 kubelet[21935]: E0225 14:30:54.830683   21935 pod_workers.go:191] Error syncing pod cec2f72b-844a-4d6b-8606-3aff06d4a36d ("calico-node-f4xzh_kube-system(cec2f72b-844a-4d6b-8606-3aff06d4a36d)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "upgrade-ipam" with ErrImagePull: "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://repo:10000/v2/calico/cni/manifests/v3.11.2: no basic auth credentials"
 kubelet[21935]: E0225 14:30:56.008989   21935 kubelet.go:2183] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
```

Feels like it's not only CNI the issue

Comment: what is the output of kubectl get pods -n kube-system? calico pods are running in kube-system namespace?

Comment: No it's not running, it says : 
calico-kube-controllers-5b644bc49c-w5cvq   0/1     Pending
calico-node-fq22h                          0/1     Init:ImagePullBackOff
Cordns are also pending

Comment: Can you kubectl describe  and kubectl logs on calico controller and calico node pods? Do you have access to download calico images from outside docker repo? What is that --image-repository=someserver?

Comment: --image-repository=someserver is my repo server in internal, we've got proxies and firewall so we manage to use an internal repo, this works for deploying docker images.
describe calico pod  says : 
- Pulling image "calico/cni:v3.11.2"
- Failed to pull image "calico/cni:v3.11.2": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
- Back-off pulling image "calico/cni:v3.11.2"
-  Error: ErrImagePull
- Error: ImagePullBackOff

Comment: @Albz yes it seems the main problem is really that it's not being able to pull `calico/cni:v3.11.2` image. Add it to your local repo and try again, if you still face problems let me know!

Comment: add output of `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` to your question

Comment: @morgwai :
NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY   STATUS                  RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-5644fb7cf6-f7lqq   0/1     Pending                 0          29m
kube-system   calico-node-f4xzh                          0/1     Init:ImagePullBackOff   0          29m
kube-system   coredns-7fb8cdf968-bbqbz                   0/1     Pending                 0          53m
kube-system   coredns-7fb8cdf968-vdnzx                   0/1     Pending                 0          53m
...

Comment: @Albz in the question, man... geez... how do you expect anyone to read what you just provided?

Comment: Yes that's done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue with Init:ImagePullBackOff was that it cannot apply image from my private repo automatically. I had to pull all images for calico from docker. Then i deleted the calico pod it's recreate itself with the newly pushed image

```
sudo docker pull private-repo/calico/pod2daemon-flexvol:v3.11.2
sudo docker pull private-repo/calico/node:v3.11.2
sudo docker pull private-repo/calico/cni:v3.11.2
sudo docker pull private-repo/calico/kube-controllers:v3.11.2

sudo kubectl -n kube-system delete po/calico-node-y7g5
```

After that the node re-do all the init phase and :

```
sudo kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
calico-kube-controllers-5644fb7cf6-qkf47   1/1     Running   0          11s
calico-node-mkcsr                          1/1     Running   0          21m
coredns-7fb8cdf968-bgqvj                   1/1     Running   0          37m
coredns-7fb8cdf968-v85jx                   1/1     Running   0          37m
etcd-lin-1k8w1dv-vmh                       1/1     Running   0          38m
kube-apiserver-lin-1k8w1dv-vmh             1/1     Running   0          38m
kube-controller-manager-lin-1k8w1dv-vmh    1/1     Running   0          38m
kube-proxy-9hkns                           1/1     Running   0          37m
kube-scheduler-lin-1k8w1dv-vmh             1/1     Running   0          38m
```

Answer (score 2):

Core DNS pod will be pending and master will be NotReady till calico pods are successfully running and CNI is setup properly.

It seems to be network issue to download calico docker images from docker.io. So you can pull calico images from docker.io and and push it to your internal container registry and then modify the calico yaml to refer that registry in images section of calico.yaml and finally apply the modified calico yaml to the kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Ok i manage to deploy calico node from my private repo. But still it is stuck with strange errors :
pod_workers.go:191] Error syncing pod cec2f72b-844a-4d6b-8606-3aff06d4a36d ("calico-node-f4xzh_kube-system(cec2f72b-844a-4d6b-8606-3aff06d4a36d)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "upgrade-ipam" with ImagePullBackOff: "Back-off pulling image \"private-repo:10000/calico/cni:v3.11.2\""
And stays in Init:ErrImagePull

Comment: Did you **really** added the calico/cni:3.11.2 on your private repo? because the error seems to be the same but now it's saying it can't pull the image from `"private-repo:10000/calico/cni:v3.11.2\"` Are you using Proxy in your network??